# carriage-return and wildcards in if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, wildcard, carriage-return

Can anyone please tell me why this doesn’t work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 

foo="hello

world"

if [[ "$foo" == *"\r\r"* ]]
then 
  echo "two carriage-returns found"
fi
```

Edit:
Freddy and WjAndrea, a million thanks! Gee, have I spent some hours trying to get that syntax correct!

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: @Sobyso : Neither `$foo` nor the pattern string contain a carriage return. You can easily verify this by doing a (for instance)  `xxd <<<"$foo"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You have carriage returns `\r` confused with newlines `\n`
2. Those `\r`s are literally backslashes followed by lowercase R's, not carriage returns

So, you could use [C-style strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) to make them special:

```
if [[ "$foo" == *$'\n\n'* ]]
```

Or put two actual newlines, but this is ugly:

```
if [[ "$foo" == *"

"* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for two newlines (line feed) `\n\n` and use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="hello

world"

if [[ $foo == *$'\n\n'* ]]; then
  echo "two newlines found"
fi
```